# Why i can't start thread in thread pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I just created function of thread:

```
static void ThreadMethod {}
```

And try this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadMethod);
```

But `QueueUserWorkItem` requests `WaitCallback` object.

It's just example from my book and looks like it must work this way. What am i missing?

Comment: Did you look up the documentation on `WaitCallback`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a typo

Not :

```
static void ThreadMethod {}
```

But :

```
static void ThreadMethod(object sender) {//Method stuff go here}
```

And call it as,

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadMethod));
```

A working minimal case + parameter passing to thread

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            paras myvalues = new paras();

            myvalues.para1 = 10;
            myvalues.para2 = 20;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadMethod),myvalues);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ThreadMethod(object state)
        {
            paras vals =(paras) state;

            Console.WriteLine(vals.para1);
            Console.WriteLine(vals.para2);

        }

    }

    struct paras
    {
        int Para1;

        public int para1
        {
            get { return Para1; }
            set { Para1 = value; }
        }

        int Para2;

        public int para2
        {
            get { return Para2; }
            set { Para2 = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i somehow make ThreadMethod with 2 arguments? I need to input into it 2 int values.

Comment: Send multiple argument in an array or dictionary

Comment: yes possible use a struct :) and pass it to state object